# SQL query that checks another table's data

Tags: php, sql, forum

I'm not too good with the more complicated SQL queries like JOIN, so I'm clueless in this aspect.

I've got three tables:

```
FORUM_Topics
FORUM_Threads
FORUM_Replies
```

A forum topic is the highest level.

A forum thread is inside a topic.

A forum reply is inside a thread.

Replies don't directly say what topic they're in, only what thread. The thread then says what topic.

So it looks sort of like this:

```
FORUM_Topics
ID = 1
Name = A topic

FORUM_Threads
ID = 1
TopicID = 1
Name = A forum thread

FORUM_Replies
ID = 1
ThreadID = 1
Name = A forum reply
```

If I wanted to see how many threads in a topic, it's as simple as:

```
$threads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FORUM_Threads WHERE TopicID = $ID");
```

but how would I check how many replies in a topic?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select FORUM_Replies.* from FORUM_Replies
inner join FORUM_Threads on FORUM_Replies.ThreadID = FORUM_Threads.ID
where FORUM_Threads.TopicID = $ID
```

You might want to get result from both Replies and Threads.

```
select FORUM_Replies.Name as ReplyName, FORUM_Threads.Name as ForumName from FORUM_Replies
inner join FORUM_Threads on FORUM_Replies.ThreadID = FORUM_Threads.ID
where FORUM_Threads.TopicID = $ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and practical response. I realy need to learn how to use the JOIN keyword at some point. Much appreciated.

Comment: Joins are really not that complicated, at least not when there is a simple match by ID as in this case. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) is a simple two page article describing how to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can't figure out why I've never understood it before, it is quite straightforward realy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you should use this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FORUM_Replies WHERE ThreadID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM FORUM_Threads WHERE TopicID = @id)
```

that should do the trick

Comment: Inner Joins are the traditional way to solve this problem. Subselects has historically been bad performance wise, but modern DBMS should generate equivalent execution plans for an inner join and a subselect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`forum_replies`.`name`) as `totals`
FROM
  `FORUM_REPLIES`
LEFT JOIN
  `forum_replies` ON(`forum_threads`.`topicid`=`forum_replies`.`threadid`)
LEFT JOIN
  `FORUM_THREDS` ON(`forum_topic`.`id`=`forum_threads`.`topicid`)
WHERE
  `forum_topics`.`id`="7";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using Ask AI to answer that, artificial intelligence worked pretty well :)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FORUM_Replies 
WHERE ThreadID IN (SELECT ID FROM FORUM_Threads WHERE TopicID = $ID)
```

The above query is optimal because it uses a subquery to get the ThreadIDs that are in the topic, and then counts the number of replies that are in those threads.

https://askainow.com/challenge/preview/cpid/558